# how to add a include path to visual studio using nsis?

Tags: visual-c++, nsis

does anyone knows how can I make my nsis installer update visual studio include path with my sdk paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In next text I assume you use Visual Studio 2008.

If you want to directly change the paths you must modify file *%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\VCComponents.dat*.

There is no need to write keys into registry, because directories are saved here.

Use this NSIS code to add directory *C:\YOUR DIRECTORY HERE* into it:

```
Function Write
SetShellvarContext current
ReadIniStr $0 "$LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\VCComponents.dat" "VC\VC_OBJECTS_PLATFORM_INFO\Win32\Directories" "Include Dirs"
WriteIniStr "$LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\VCComponents.dat" "VC\VC_OBJECTS_PLATFORM_INFO\Win32\Directories" "Include Dirs" "$0;C:\YOUR DIRECTORY HERE"
IfErrors Error NoError
Error:
  MessageBox MB_OK "Cound not write!"
NoError:
FunctionEnd
```

Be carefull with this because there are many options.
Ini typically looks like this:

[PLATFORM]

Directories=Dir1;Dir2;$(VSVariable)path

Above example writes directory into **Win32** and **Include files**. See the picture to understand it.

[image]

For Visual Studio 2010 the format has been changed (to XML):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create batch file (.bat) where you set PATH variable (add your SDK directory to the PATH) - this may be dependent on Windows version you use. Visual Studio searches PATH automatically.

Then simple use `nsExec::ExecToStack` to run this bat file in quiet mode.

Comment: That could be a good option, but nsis can edit environment variables direct I think. But is there anyway to set the include path direct?

Answer (score 0):

NSIS does not have any specific support for VS but you can edit any registry setting with [ReadRegStr and WriteRegStr](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.2)

Comment: ok, I was not expecting any direct support for Visual, but do you know which keys I should edit for adding a include path? Thanks